# Windows XP folders disappear on startup

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Folders disappear every timeWindows XP starts up](https://superuser.com/questions/131492/folders-disappear-every-timewindows-xp-starts-up)

This is the same question raised previously as

> Whenever my Windows XP machine starts up, subfolders disappear from the first top-level folder, listed alphabetically (eg. from "C:\AA Backups"). The first time it happened I suspected user error (such as an unintention.

Was this problem solved?

Comment: Can you please share the link to this question you're talking about? I'm sure not everybody knows all the 110,620 others by heart.

Comment: To answer your question: No, it obviously wasn't solved, otherwise you would've read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a antivirus / spyware scan ?, this is very odd indeed. Try downloading and scanning your computer with something like Malware Bytes, this will rule out viruses or spyware as the cause.